# Possible to combine WSS and basic auth for a Java based webservice?

Tags: java, soap, wss

we're using a Soap based webservice in Java 1.6 that implements WSS security via token. There will be a new consumer of that webservice who wants to do auth via basic auth. Question is now: is it possible to enhance the existing webservice, so that one consumer can connect via WSS and the other one via basic auth?

Thanks, Regards
Jens

Comment: It is possible to use basic authentication since soap is a http service and http supports basic authentication. If you are asking how to implement then it's is too broad of a question for stack overflow.

Comment: That wasn't my question. We're able to implement basic auth, but struggle to combine it with existing WSS security, auth depending on the consumer.

Comment: Are you using WSS4J?

Comment: As far as I understand, yes. It is Axis2 and Rampart, this should be based on WSS4J